# I can inspect a button when I use a website and get its XPath, but when I use a bot to open this website, I can not find it in the Elements Panel

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When I open a website by myself, I am able to find the XPath of a button that I want to click. But when I use a bot to open this website I can not find it in the Elements Panel. I still can see the button on the website, but not in the Elements Panel. Does someone know what I should do?

I already tried to use the XPath that I got by entering in the website normally and see if the bot could click on it, but I did not work.

Comment: Without your code trials, error stack and details about the application like it's URL or HTML, no one will be able to help you. So edit your question and share all these details. Then the community here can help you. Else your question will be marked as closed. Refer this - [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)